# In OS, Can a page have different areas?

Tags: operating-system

My Question is Can a page have different areas?

I understand Page is a fixed-length contiguous block of virtual memory(Logical address).
And Here's what I'm confused about.
I understand that the text, data, heap, and stack areas of logical addresses have continuous addresses. So, **"Can a page have different areas?"** So how is it managed?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJUV4.jpg)